# Add Post type menu to another menu

Tags: custom-post-types, admin-menu

I've created a menu page in the dashboard, then I created a custom post type and now I want to put the menu of the custom post type as a submenu under the first menu page I had created. I tried

'show_in_menu' => 'admin.php?page=mytestpage',

However that did not work. Any tips?

Comment: DO you want to add the Custom Post under an Admin menu item? like: Post -> Custom post ?

Comment: Yes but not under Post, under one of my custom created menu items.

Comment: way not the other way around? create the custom post type and add your custom page as sub page to that.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, operation successful thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up creating the custom post type and adding my custom page as sub page to that, as suggested by Bainternet

Answer (score 6):

You only need to add the page slug to "show_in_menu", making the answer to your example:

```
'show_in_menu' => 'mytestpage',
```

For a more complete example:

Admin/Settings page of: /wp-admin/admin.php?page=mytestpage

```
register_post_type('mycpt', array('label' => 'My Custom Post Type', 'capability_type' => 'post', 'show_ui' => true, 'show_in_menu' => 'mytestpage'));
```

Comment: I did this and it failed to move the menu under the desired menu. :-(((( 

It did however remove the menu. 

'show_in_menu' => 'mytestpage' is what I used. :-((((

I removed it and all was well again. 

Any other suggestions ???